# How to stop antivirus false positives everytime we re-release software?

Tags: anti-virus

Windows Defender and AVG/Avast pickup our software application as a virus/false positive everytime we release. We have a code signing certificate and add taggant as well.

Every time we release the software we have to go through the process of doing a false positive form on multiple AV vendors sites.

How can we get our company code signing cert marked as safe or avoid this time consuming false positive report process on each release?

Comment: Contact with microsoft and avg/avast company.

Comment: All I get is a generic email saying our specific hash has been whitelisted. Any suggestions of who exactly to contact?

Comment: Found another solution. Add a stub to our program which looks like a normal non packed/obfuscated program. As most anti virus programs only analyse only the first few kilobytes of the program this stops it determining our program is packed/obfuscated and doesn't trigger the false detections.

Comment: How did you go about doing this @rolls ?